# image on same position for all screen resolution

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a wordpress blog theme [link](http://www.marketingwithyou.com/blog/). There is a profile image on the left side. It is now accurate according to my screen resolution that is 1152*864.

Problem occurs when I test this site with different screen resolutions. It is getting more space between the image and the content.

Is there any solution that it should be compatible for all the screen resolutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you want to 'text-align: center;' your 'div.contentImg'. then add a 'margin-left: -850px;' to the image.

```
<style>
    .contentImg {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .contentImg img {
        margin-left: -850px;
    }
</style>
```

good luck!